# How to get the meshes name from the object name

Tags: python, scripting

In Blender, object names and meshes names may be different, as in Cube2 and Cube.001.
[image]

Is there a way to get the meshes name from the object name using Python?

Also,Is there only one meshes node per Object?

Comment: `obj.name` gives you the object name. `obj.data.name` gives you mesh name. And yes, AFAIK there can be only one mesh per object. However there can be multiple objects sharing the same mesh data block.

Comment: @BlenderDadaist you could post this as an answer.

Comment: @rjg I have put that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj.name` gives you the object name. `obj.data.name` gives you mesh name. And yes, AFAIK there can be only one mesh per object. However there can be multiple objects sharing the same mesh data block.